# Verifying valid public key and finding private key?

Tags: rsa, public-key, file-encryption, verifiability

A naive user of RSA has announced the public key $n = 2903239, e = 5$.
Eve has worked out that $n = 1237×2347$. Verify that the public key is valid
and explain why the private key is $d = 2319725$. [Calculators are not
required.]

This question comes from a mock exam that I am trying to solve for tomorrow.

I attach my working out:

$n = p\;q = (1237)(2347) = 2903239$

$\varphi(n) = (1237-1)(2347-1) = 1236(2346) = 2899656$

$d\;e \bmod \varphi(n) = 1$

$e = 5$

$5\;d \bmod 2899656 = 1$

Applying the Euclidean algorithm:

$5\;x + 2899656\;y = 1$

$2899656 = 5(579931)+1$

- The public key part: $(e,n) = (5, 2903239)$
- The private key part: $(d,n) = (2319725,1)$

I do not understand how the private key is calculated, nor how to do this with a calculator. Any help would be welcome.

**EDIT:**
$$\varphi (n) = (1237-1)(2347-1)= 2899656 \neq 2903239$$

de mod (phi(n)) = 1

5d mod 2903239 = 1

5x + 2903239y = 1

2903239 = 5(580647)+4

5 = 4(1) + 1

1 = 5 - 4(1)

1 = 5 - (2903239 - 5(580647)

1 = 5 - 2903239 + 5(580647)

1 = 5(580648) - 1(2903239)

I am still unsure of how to obtain the private key value from this.

2903239 - 5860648 = 2322591

This value is not the same as the desired value of d, d = 2319725.

Comment: Look for [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) or see [Modular Multiplicative Inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) or search for `ext GCD examples`. If you don't do it now, you won't in the exam.

Comment: Please see edit. I have reviewed that example.

Comment: take $\mod  2903239$ you will get $1 \equiv 5 \cdot 580648 \bmod  2903239$. don't you see the inverse of $5$ now? But there is a calculation error right.

Comment: Note that you don't need to obtain the private key, since it is given. You only need to verify that the given key is correct.

Comment: (Also, in principle you should also verify that 1237 and 2347 are prime.)

Comment: I don't really know how to progress having applied the extended euclidean algorithm :/

Comment: The inverse of $5$ for $\bmod \varphi$ not $\bmod n$. Did you look at the duplicate link? in Edit part it is taken as 2903239 but should be 2899656

Comment: Odd, I get $d = 386621$; that certainly works as a decryption exponent.  Your textbook might be wrong...